# My eye is turning black when adding the transmission on the BSDF node

Tags: node-editor

I'm trying to make an eye and while adding the outer later that makes it shine it's turning it dark instead. 
It's supposed to look like this:
[image]
But ends up looking like this:
[image]

Does anyone know what's up?
Here's my blend file.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's mostly the lighting.  In the example it looks like they're using an environment like an HDR map or something, but in your scene you just have 2 lights.   I just added this:

[image]

and I got this:

[image]

...which is much closer to the example.  Of course the other main difference is the tutorial is using Blender 2.8 and yours looks like 2.7x, which will have differences.

Comment: Thanks. It works now, one more question, do you know how to get the scene to be less grainy in rendered mode?

Comment: you need first to increase the Samples value in the Render panel > Sampling

Comment: Alright then, thanks.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to increase the samples. I'd try setting the "Clamp Indirect" setting to 0.9 instead of 0.  That should clear up the bright speckles.   Also if you found my answer useful you should mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you could set an answer as correct. Just did, thanks again, I'll have to try the clamp indirect.

Answer (score 1):

He's in Eevee, maybe that setup works fine in Eevee, but in Cycles I think you need at least to mix your *Principled BSDF* (with 1.00 *Transmission*) with a *Transparent BSDF* node. There is a lot of solutions (like use *Fresnel* in the *Mix* factor, use *Glossy*, etc) but it will always be a mix with *Transparent BSDF* in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll have to do further tweaking to see if it works, it made the eye clearer though I couldn't see the shell at all.